# unterminated s command with seed on special characters with sed

Tags: text-processing, variable-substitution, special-characters

i have special characters in the content of $VALUE which I would to add in file (`$FILE`).

When I run this cammand :

```
sed -i "s|T_VALUE|$VALUE|" "$FILE"
```

i have an error unterminated s command

i saw some post saying i need to escape the special characters, but i do not know them upfront as `$VALUE` is a dynamic value.
how can i solve this?

Comment: it did not help because I am still getting the error, any example that escape all the special character?

Comment: Use other delimiter, in this case pipe do other things

Comment: See [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Perl for fancier quoting. To avoid confusion, you can pass arguments via environment variables.

```bash
$ SUB_LH='?|'
$ SUB_RH='/\'
$ cat mydata.txt
x?|y
?|ab?|
$ SUB_LH=$SUB_LH SUB_RH=$SUB_RH perl -p -i.bak -e 's/\Q$ENV{SUB_LH}\E/$ENV{SUB_RH}/g' mydata.txt
$ cat mydata.txt
x/\y
/\ab/\
```

Comment: Is this solution restricted to particular shells, and/or shell versions?

Comment: @jubilatious1 i don't think so, well at least for posix `sh`. no idea about `csh` and friends